# Remover tag (strip_tags()) html junto com o conteúdo - PHP

Tags: php

Quando utilizo a função interna `strip_tags()` para remover uma tag `html`, ela remove somente a tag em si `<p></p>`. Mas gostaria que também fosse removido o seu conteúdo `<p>teste</p>`. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Não é melhor usar `JavaScript`?

Comment: Neste caso especifico preciso utilizar somente PHP. Pois é somente uma manutenção em uma classe já existente. @ShutUpMagda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) { 
  preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags); 
  $tags = array_unique($tags[1]); 

  if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) { 
    if($invert == FALSE) { 
      return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
    } else { 
      return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
    } 
  } elseif ($invert == FALSE) { 
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
  } 
  return $text; 
} 

$text = '<b>sample</b> text with <div>tags</div>'; 
strip_tags_content($text): 
// saída: text with
```

fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php#86964

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar `preg_replace`

```
$yourString = 'Hello <div>Planet</div> Earth. This is some <span class="foo">sample</span> content! <p>Hello</p>';
$regex = '/<[^>]*>[^<]*<[^>]*>/';
echo preg_replace($regex, '', $yourString);
```

**Isso retornará:**

> Hello Earth. This is some content!

Caso precise remover uma tag em específico, pode ser feito desta maneira:

```
echo preg_replace('/<h1[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/h1[^>]*>/', '', 'Hello<h1>including this content</h1> There !!');
```

**Isso retornará**

> Hello There

Existe um tópico no stackoverflow em inglês
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630159/strip-tags-and-everything-in-between